# jQuery animating along a bezier curve, irregular y-axis offset appears per cycle

Tags: jquery, animation, bezier

I'm basically animating an object over a sin wave. However, it only traverses a segment once, whereas I need it to continually traverse.

I am repeating the animation recursively for it to follow the path, rather than how it would normally restart back at the beginning.

However, each repeat of the cycle drops the element slightly lower at the beginning of the next cycle.

How can I make this follow the curve seamlessly?

**View Demonstration:**http://jsfiddle.net/nfeZF/121/

---

```
function float(dir){
    var x_current = $("div").offset().left;
    var y_current = $("div").offset().top;
    var SineWave = function() {
        // this is called every step in the animation over 6000 miliseconds, updating the x/y coordinates
        // with sin rules applied to follow the curve
        // repeating this cycle (each timeout callback) drops the 
        // object about 50-100 pixels down from where it left off
        this.css = function(p) {
            var s = Math.sin(p*10);
            if (!dir){
                // swap the direction to continue on the path
                s = -s;   
            }
            var x =  300-p * 300;
            var y = s * 100 + 100;
            var o = ((s+2)/4+0.1);
            // add the current x-position to continue the path, rather than restarting
            return {top: y + "px", left: x_current + x + "px"};
        } 
    };

    $("div").animate({
        path: new SineWave
    }, 6000, 'linear', function(){
        // avoid exceeding stack
        setTimeout(float(!dir), 0);
    });

}
```